# Show erros in hibernate spring-data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm working in a spring mvc project using spring data jpa and hibernate, I am using native queries that I declare in a interface that extends JpaRepository like this:

```
public interface I_Table_one extends JpaRepository<table_id, Long>{

    @Query(value ="select name_att, .... .... various att"
            + "from Table_one "
            + "where id_table = 4 ", 
           nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Table_one_Mapped_Class>serachInTable();
```

This method doesn't have to much sense is just a example, I have one that have like 80 attributes in the select I just one to know is there is a way to know what column name I have wrong.

My mapped class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table_one")
public class Table_one_Mapped_Class implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

////ID///////
                @Id
                @Column (name="ID_TABLE", nullable=false)
                private Long idInMyTable;
////ID///////
 .....other columns
```

This is my hibernate properties configuration:

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
           jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
           jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
           jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
```

and I get the following error when i try to print a value from my controller class in a html page  like this `${value}`

I get this error in the console :

> WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 99999
>   ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid Column Name

and this error when I try to open the page

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

In the console says:

> invalid column name

but how can I know what column have a invalid name, is in the query that I put in the interface method, or is a invalid name of an attribute in my mapped class

I have seen similar problems and what person posted that I need to select ALL the columns in the select in order to work, but why I only need a few column in my select do I need to select all of the column even if don't need them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Data JPA >1.4, you could create a DTO-Class containing exactly the attributes you need from your table(s).

A sample-DTO and -Query would look like this, then:

The Query:

```
@Query("select new de.mypackage.mymodel.dto.myDTO(name_Att, att2,, att3)" +
        " from Table_One " +
        "where ...")
List<myDTO> getAttributesFromBigTable(String name_Attribute, 
                String attribute2, String attribute3);
```

The DTO:

```
    public class myDTO {

    private String name_attr;
    private String attr2;
    private String attr3;

    public myDTO(String name_attr, String attr2, String attr3) {
        this.name_attr = name_attr;
        this.attr2 = attr2;
        this.attr3 = attr3;
    }

    public String getName_Attr() {
       return name_attr;
    }
...
}
```