# How to automatically create an entity from database tables?

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

I'm using `spring-batch` to fetch some data from a database.
If I use `SELECT * FROM...` my resultset is a list of `@Entity` classes, which is desired.

But I only want to fetch some attributes (columns) of the entity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a, b) a, c, d
FROM mytable [...]
```

Therefore I created a constructor accordingly that matches the columns fetched:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private int id;

    public MyEntity(String a, BigDecimal c, Date d) {
        //setter
    }
}
```

Result:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
PSQLException: The column id was not found in ResultSet
```

This is my reader definition:

```
JpaPagingItemReader<MyEntity> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<MyEntity>();
JpaNativeQueryProvider<MyEntity> queryProvider = new JpaNativeQueryProvider<>();
queryProvider.setSqlQuery(SQL);
reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
```

How can I let automatically create the entity if I do not fetch the whole row content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JPA queries as

```
select new bar.foo.entity.custom.CustomEntity (u.id, u.username, u.firstName, u.surname, u.email) from UserAccount u order by u.username ASC
```

Please note the **new** keyword and the **pojo** declaration. That is where the magic happens.

Comment: what is `e.*` here? And on which position do I have to place `DISTINCT ON`?

Comment: well, your question was how to get some attributes so there is no e.*. RE the distinct, you can use as DISTINCT(e.username).

Comment: I meant: what does the `e` in your example query stand for? Because it is not defined anywhere... And should I write `SELECT NEW bar..CustomEntity(..) DISTINCT ON(..) FROM ..` or `SELECT DISTINCT ON(..) NEW bar..CustomEntity(..) FROM ..`?

Comment: The distinct, I would need to run the code and try. Sorry. I wrote from the top of my head.

Comment: Hm I tried it (without the distinct), but constantly getting: `ERROR: Syntaxerror on ?.?`

Comment: hmm.. the select new came to spring data jpa with version 1.4 afair, could it be your version is lower? Apart from that, I just created a very similar example (although in another context) right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916477/show-erros-in-hibernate-spring-data-jpa, may be that it helps you out on this, too. I've not used spring batch so far, so not sure if it's valid in this scenario, but looks very familiar, so here my comment-hint ;)

Comment: I'm using spring data 1.4.2 if I'm not wrong. I've used in a couple of places to retrieve data that is not an JPA entity.